# Mocking the model and its methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec

**Can anyone tell me whether my approach is fine?**

I want to know the `api` we are using is working as designed and when it changes so we know that has changed without having to dig through all the `code` logic. We will provide a set of arguments, we expect a certain result so that my unit tests work well.

```
User.login({email: username, password: password);
```

The above method in my model actually hits the API and returns me a response. I want to check whether my Model's login method work as intended.

Below is my `approach`.

I am stubbing my login method in my model with required params and expected response, to avoid hitting the api and then expecting the `login` method to `derive` the same response.
I am using ActiveRestClient.

Below is my model

```
class User << ActiveRestClient::Base
  get :all, '/user'
  get :find, '/user/:id'
end
```

Below is my spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do 

  let(:username) {"test@test.com"}
  let(:password) {"123"}

  context "when signing in" do 
    let(:response) {{token: "123"}.to_json}

    it "should sign in with valid input" do 
      allow(User).to receive(:login).with({email: username, password: 
           password}).and_return(response)
      expect(User.login({email: username, password: passwor})).to eq(response)
    end

  end

end
```

**Can anyone tell me whether my approach is fine?**

Comment: No, I am sorry, your approach is not fine. Because it does not test a single line of code. The only thing your spec is testing is that the `User.login` stub returns what you told it to return.

Answer (score 0):

No, I am sorry, your approach is not fine. Because it does not test a single line of our code. The only thing your spec is testing is that the `User.login` stub returns what you told it to return.

If you want to speed up your specs by stubbing methods, than you should look for calls in your method that touch the database. Something like `User.find_by_email` in the following example (And I guess you do something similar in your `login` method).

Furthermore you may want to spec want happens if the `email` or the `password` does not match.

```
describe User do 
  describe 'login' do
    let(:username)  { "test@test.com" }
    let(:password)  { "password" }
    subject(:login) { User.login(email: username, password: password) }

    context 'when user do not exists' do
      before { allow(User).to receive(:find_by_email).and_return(nil) }

      it 'returns nil' do
        expect(login).to be_nil
      end
    end

    context 'when user exists' do
      before do
        allow(User).to receive(:find_by_email).with(username).and_return(user)
      end

      context 'when password does not match' do
        let(:user) { User.new(:password => 'wrong password') }

        it 'returns nil' do
          expect(login).to be_nil
        end
      end

      context 'when password matches' do
        let(:user) { User.new(:password => password, :generate_token => 123) }

        it 'returns a json containing the signin token' do
          expect(login).to eq "{'token':'123'}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Since I have no idea what your `login` method really does, all specs above are just based on assumptions and will very like not pass with your implementation. But I hope you get the point.